# Log4j2 won't log into file in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I'm using Spring boot and Gradle build tools. I want to add a logger which logging my events. I chose Log4j2. first of all, I have added these dependencies:

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.14.1'

implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.14.1'
```

then added this configuration file, to my resources folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="logs/log4j2-demo.log"
                 filePattern="log4j2-demo-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />

        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

then I use it via this command:

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Application.class);
logger.error("Hello from Log4j 2");
```

I'm in doubt that Spring uses the configuration file at all. Because it won't create the *log* folder and *log4j2-demo.log* file. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging

Comment: This tutorial says to exclude an artifact and it resolves my problem. thank you @SimonMartinelli

Comment: Great! Please add Your solution as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `LoggerFactory`

```
 private static final Logger LGR = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ObjectsController.class);
```